# Add Dynamic Column in Array in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a 'MainModel' which Contains StudentStrengthList, and i need a Collection(List/Array) with dynamic section names. Currently i' m getting static section names.I need this data for chart.

My Models :-

```
public class MainModel
{
public List<StudentStrenghtModel> StudentStrengthList { get; set; }
}

public class StudentStrengthList
 {
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public int Sec1 { get; set; } //Contains Strength of Section 'A'
    public int Sec2 { get; set; } //Contains Strength of Section 'B'
    public int Sec3 { get; set; } //Contains Strength of Section 'C'
    public int Sec4 { get; set; } //Contains Strength of Section 'D'
    public int Sec5 { get; set; } //Contains Strength of Section 'E'
    public int Total { get; set; } //Contains Total Strength
}
```

My C# Code :-

```
        var result = model.StudentStrengthList.Select(r => new
        {
            ClassName = r.ClassName + "(" + r.Total + ")",
            A = r.Sec1, //Need These Section Names Should Be Dynamic i.e 'A' Can be 'A (Commerce)'
            B = r.Sec2,
            C = r.Sec3,
            D = r.Sec4,
            E = r.Sec5
        }).ToList();
```

My Result :-

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you meant by dynamic column?

Comment: Currently i m taking 'A-E' as my Sections but it can be more then or less then 'A-E'

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
Always __TAG__ your question correctly! - Also: What section names?? I see none. Also: what chart?

Comment: To make the number and name dynamic you can use a `Dictionary<string, int> sections`.

Comment: It was web based MVC5 Application and i m using this data for making a bar chart.You can see section names in my result section. A,B,C,D,E are section names.

Comment: I see the result but not where it comes from or where the data reside.

Comment: It was comes from property of 'StudentStrengthList'  in 'MainModel' in the form of 'StudentStrengthList' Model

Comment: OK. To make things dynamic at runtime usually a collection is used. For simple fields a List<T>, for key-value data a Dictionary<K,V> etc.. For a dynamic number of `StudentStrengthList/Classes`  with a dynamic number of sections you can use a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>`. Or you can change the `StudentStrengthList` class to contain a `List<int> sections` and put the whole data into a `List<StudentStrengthList/Classes>`. Not sure which..

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, I ended using enums that I am using any way stating what type of data as the index for the array. this way my enum becomes a column name

I declared it like so, please note that one needs to use the highest value
of the enum to initialize the array, you can enter the number or use the value so that when it blows up as you changed your enum you can see where this is all effected.

The array:

```
var candle= new Tick[(int)TickTypes.Last];
```

I'd set the value like so:

```
var tick= new Tick(){TickType=TickTypes.Last, Price=aPrice, Date=tickDate};
candle[(int)tick.TickType]= tick;
```

Now I can return the value by providing the enum as column name and I can read/ write over the list without having it blow up on me because another thread updated my list.

Sometimes it is hard to ask the exchange to stop trading as my program is processing a list.

This way you can have a 2 dimensional grid (rows & columns) that are thread safe and dynamic (show only those with a value).